# How can I export dmp oracle db into csv format?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, export-to-csv, dump

I've got a dataset which is **Oracle dump file**.I wan to export it into csv format which is possible with some convertors like [this](http://www.convert-in.com/ord2csv.htm) one. But this convertor is not free and on the other hand I can not purchase it cause I'm living in Iran (not provided in my country).
I don't know Oracle as well but I installed Oracle express and tried to import the DB but I couldn't. Could You Please Help me ?
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: What's the error on import?

Comment: @vercelli there is no clear error on this.When the upload finishes nothing happens and still there is written importing file.

Comment: Maybe the file is to big. Oracle Express has some a limitations on that "the maximum amount of user data in an Oracle Database XE Server database cannot exceed 4 gigabytes"

Comment: That screenshot is Oracle Application Express and the import interface allows you to import/export applications that are built with Application Express. It is not for importing a schema dump. Install Oracle SQL Developer and use that to import your dump file (or learn how to use commandline tools exp/imp).